# How to display nodes that belong to a certain term twice on the same page using Views in D7?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

is it possible to display nodes that belong to a certain term twice on the same page?

This is my case:

1. I use Taxonomy Term view to display term pages. That one has a page display that uses "taxonomy/term/%" path to overwrite regular term pages
2. Taxonomy Term view is used to display 10 items, but with the offset of 1 item (first item is skipped).
3. I would like to display the first item in a separate block in one of the sidebars.

I hoped that this can be achieved with just copying the settings of the Taxonomy Term view "page" display to a "block" display, i. e. with using the same "has taxonomy term ID" contextual filters, but it doesn't get displayed.

How can this be achieved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you probably just need to adjust where the block display's contextual filter gets its argument, the tid, from.  there are many options.  you can get it from the url or the page.  fiddle with those and it will work.

Comment: @Jimajamma Thank you! It does work - I just had to change "When the filter value is NOT available" part to "Provide default value" - "Taxonomy term ID from URL".

Comment: glad it was a quick fix!